# Install/Update cifs-utils before mount smb

Tags: linux, powershell, ssh, vagrant, hyper-v

I'm currently trying to get Vagrant to provision a working CentoOS7 image on Windows10, using Hyper-V. Vagrant 1.8.4, current latest.

I envcounter a problem where the provisioning fails and I need to workaround each time. The CentOS7 image is a minimal image and does not include `cifs-utils`, therefore the mount wont work. So, I need `cifs-utils` installed before mount.

Error:

```
==> default: Mounting SMB shared folders...
    default: C:/Programs/vagrant_stuff/centos7 => /vagrant
Failed to mount folders in Linux guest. This is usually because
the "vboxsf" file system is not available. Please verify that
the guest additions are properly installed in the guest and
can work properly. The command attempted was:

mount -t cifs -o uid=`id -u vagrant`,gid=`getent group vagrant | cut -d: -f3`,sec=ntlm,credentials=/etc/smb_creds_4d99b2
d500a1bcb656d5a1c481a47191 //192.168.137.1/4d99b2d500a1bcb656d5a1c481a47191 /vagrant
mount -t cifs -o uid=`id -u vagrant`,gid=`id -g vagrant`,sec=ntlm,credentials=/etc/smb_creds_4d99b2d500a1bcb656d5a1c481a
47191 //192.168.137.1/4d99b2d500a1bcb656d5a1c481a47191 /vagrant

The error output from the last command was:

mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on //192.168.137.1/4d99b2d500a1bcb656d5a1c481a47191,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error
       (for several filesystems (e.g. nfs, cifs) you might
       need a /sbin/mount.<type> helper program)

       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       dmesg | tail or so.
```

As it is now, the provisioning has to fail, and I need to:

`vagrant ssh` (powershell)

(connect to instance via putty/ssh)

`sudo yum install cifs-utils -y` (putty/ssh)

(wait for install...)

`exit` (putty/ssh)

`vagrant reload --provision` (powershell)

This is obviously a pain and I am trying to streamline the process.

*Does anyone know a better way?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently my original question was downvoted for some reason. #whatever

As I mentioned in one of the comments above:

I managed to repackage and upload an updated version. Thanks for the advice. Its available in Atlas as ["KptnKMan/bluefhypervalphacentos7repack"](https://atlas.hashicorp.com/KptnKMan/boxes/bluefhypervalphacentos7repack).

Special thanks to @frédéric-henri  :)

Answer (score 1):

You can install the missing package in your box and [repackage](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/cli/box.html#repackage) this box so you can distribute a new version of this box containing the missing package.

Comment: I've considered this approach, as I'm using boxes from Atlas.
I've tried both of these boxes and seen the same problem:
`serveit/centos-7` and `bluefedora/hyperv-alpha-centos7`

Comment: what you could do is repackage the box after you installed the missing package and publish as a new box on atlas

Comment: I managed to repackage and upload an updated version. Thanks for the advice. Its available in Atlas as ["KptnKMan/bluefhypervalphacentos7repack"](https://atlas.hashicorp.com/KptnKMan/boxes/bluefhypervalphacentos7repack). :) @frédéric-henri

Comment: good, feel free to [upvote](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-to-upvote-on-stack-overflow) if usefull

Answer (score 0):

In order to provision a vagrant box you need to create it from an iso. While preparing the box you can install all needed packages for you. In your case it is Hyper-v - https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/hyperv/boxes.html

Best Regards

Comment: At the moment I'm not creating my own box using an ISO, but I think soon enough I may have a crack at producing my own and uploading it to Atlas. This seems like an annoying error to me, and appears to be simply about missing pre-required binaries.